# Modify array in loop using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php multidimensional array(A) and I want to build another array(B) from that array A

My code is

```
$question = array(
    "ques_15" => array(
        "name" => array(
            "0" => "aaa"
        )
    ),
    "ques_16" => array(
        "name" => array(
            "0" => "bbb",
            "1" => "ccc"
        )
    )
);
$i=0;
foreach($question as $k=>$v)
{
    list(,$qid) = explode("_",$k);
    $filename .= $question[$k]['name'][$i]."#&";
    $insertData[]  = array(':quid'=>$qid,':answer'=>$filename);
    $i++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($insertData);
echo '</pre>';
```

It prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [:quid] => 15
            [:answer] => aaa#&
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [:quid] => 16
            [:answer] => aaa#&ccc#&
        )

)
```

But I want it to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [:quid] => 15
            [:answer] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [:quid] => 16
            [:answer] => aaa#&ccc
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$filename .= (empty($filename) ? '' : '#&') . $question[$k]['name'][$i];
```

If `aaa#&ccc` is a typo and it should be `bbb#&ccc`, then you can simply do:

```
foreach($question as $k=>$v)
{
    list(,$qid) = explode("_",$k);
    $filename = implode("#&", $v['name']);
    $insertData[]  = array(':quid'=>$qid,':answer'=>$filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the answer key is getting blank :(

Comment: @Raj then explain why do you want `aaa#&ccc` and not `bbb&ccc`? Works [here](http://ideone.com/yQrUPS)

Comment: Extremely sorry yes that's a typo, it should be bbb&ccc

Comment: Awesome...brilliant!!...it worked using implode...thanks a lot @meze

Answer (score 4):

```
$i=0;

foreach($question as $k=>$v)
{
    list(,$qid) = explode("_",$k);   
    $insertData[$i][':quid'] = $qid;
    $insertData[$i][':answer'] = implode('#&',$v['name']);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "#&" and place it in condition. It will work;

Just Add a condition.

> ```
> $filename .= $question[$k]['name'][$i];
> if(!empty($filename)){
>   $filename .= '#&';
> }
> ```